# Где в safari 10.1.2 в devtools стили элемента?

Tags: macos, safari, инструменты-разработчика

Не могу найти стили элемента в devtools safari 10.1.2.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Жмёшь правую кнопку.
2. В появившейся панели средний из трёх вариантов будет стилями.
3. Если его нажать и удерживать, то появится дропдаун для выбора одного из трёх режимов отображения стилей.

[image: Пометил кнопку]